Issue in implementing Submit Form using Apps Script
I have a form that starts with one multiple choice item that, based on each answer chosen, will go to a specific page for them to fill out a griditem.
For the first multiple choice item, you can only chose one answer for this item. Once chosen, the user will be take to the specific page and the user fills out a griditem. After they fill out the griditem, I want them to submit the form from this page. However this is not what happens
The code navigates to the correct page as desired but depending on the first multiple choice question, there are a certain amount of pages the use can then click 'next' and access the other pages.
For example, there are 3 multiple choice answers for the first item, choosing option 1 would take you to option 1, then option 2, and option 3 then submit. Choosing option 2 would take you to option 2, then option 3, then submit. And choosing option 3 would take you to option 3 then submit. I want it to submit after each option.
function myFunction() {

var form = FormApp.create('Scores Form').setDescription('Description');
var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
create_choice_array = []
var dict = {'page-one':['row-one','row-two'],'page-two':['row-one','row-two'],'page-three':['row-one','row-two']}
for(var key in dict){
  var value = dict[key];
  var team_ex = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(key);
  var griditem = form.addGridItem()
  .setTitle("Scores for ".concat(" ",key))
  .setRequired(true)
  .setColumns(['Did not attend', 'slightly/not engaged in activity','moderately engaged in activity', 'very engaged in activity'])
  .setRows(value);
  create_choice_array.push(item.createChoice(key,team_ex));
  //the line of code below does not work as desired
  //FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT;
}
item.setChoices([create_choice_array.pop(),create_choice_array.pop(),create_choice_array.pop()]);
//the line of code below does not work as desired
//FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT;
}

In order for submit form to happen in the correct place, I wrote this line of code in the for loop and then tried it after the for loop, but nothing changed.
FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT;
Am I placing the PageNavigationType in the wrong part of the code? Am I not accessing the items correctly? Thank you. I tried adapting some of the knowledge from these two posts but I am lost, this is my first time using apps.
How to get the PageNavigationType to work through a loop
Choices Set To a Section, Next Section, or Submit Form in Google Forms

The likelihood is that the "After section" value for each section containing the Grid items says "Continue to next section" rather than "Submit Form".

That is correct. I want to write code that will update it to Submit Form but the two commented lines of code do not do that. Please advise thank you.

Direct answers from a multiple choice question to specific pages/sections AND submit the form after answering those questions. The OP code is almost complete. Missing elements are:
Make Multiple Choice "required"

Existing line: var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
Revised line: var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("My Multiple Choice question").setRequired(true)

Assign setGoToPage
Existing lines:
var team_ex = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(key)
var griditem = form.addGridItem()

Revised lines:
var team_ex = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(key);
team_ex.setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT); // At end of page , submit form
var griditem = form.addGridItem()

Complete revised script
function buildForm() {

  var form = FormApp.create('Scores Form').setDescription('so_78498057')
  var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle("My Multiple Choice question").setRequired(true)
  create_choice_array = []
  var dict = {'page-one':['row-one','row-two'],'page-two':['row-one','row-two'],'page-three':['row-one','row-two']}
  for(var key in dict){
    var value = dict[key];
    var team_ex = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(key);
    team_ex.setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT); // At end of page , submit form
    var griditem = form.addGridItem()
    .setTitle("Scores for ".concat(" ",key))
    .setRequired(true)
    .setColumns(['Did not attend', 'slightly/not engaged in activity','moderately engaged in activity', 'very engaged in activity'])
    .setRows(value);
    create_choice_array.push(item.createChoice(key,team_ex));
  }
  item.setChoices([create_choice_array.pop(),create_choice_array.pop(),create_choice_array.pop()]);
}

References
PageBreakItem
